# Integrating Stripe with .Net Application

Tags: .net, stripe-payments

I am looking to integrate stripe payment services into my .Net application . I want this to happen in a 
seamless way where the user does not have to leave our website . Can I get some pointers towards like some documentation or code .

Comment: Stripe Payment Integration in Asp.net Web Forms and its 100 percent  working code and you can also download application 
https://code2night.com/Blog/MyBlog/Implement-Stripe-Payment-Gateway-In-ASPNET

Comment: Check out the demo app and download the code to accept payments and subscriptions with all payment methods with Stripe's newest product, Payment Element --> https://techtolia.com/Stripe/New/

Answer (score 2):

You have several options here, none of which are officially supported by Stripe (i.e. they are all third-party libraries):

1. Stripe.NET by Jayme Davis: https://github.com/jaymedavis/stripe.net
2. Xamarin Stripe by the folks at Xamarin: https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinStripe
3. ServiceStack C# API by the folks at ServiceStack: https://github.com/ServiceStack/Stripe

I have just used Stripe.NET in a development setting and decided not to go ahead with it. Its easier to just have an HTML form and handle the POST using Stripe.js library.

Source: https://stripe.com/docs/libraries

EDIT: [This](https://cmatskas.com/processing-payments-and-being-pci-compliant-with-stripe-js/?utm_content=buffer55d56&utm_medium=social&utm_source=twitter.com&utm_campaign=buffer) is a good resource on how to integrate Stripe with a .NET MVC application.

Comment: Stripe Payment Integration in Asp.net Web Forms and its 100 percent  working code and you can also download application 
https://code2night.com/Blog/MyBlog/Implement-Stripe-Payment-Gateway-In-ASPNET

Answer (score 1):

There is official documentation at Stripe for .Net applications.

https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create?lang=dotnet

An example charge call would be:

```
StripeConfiguration.SetApiKey("API_KEY");

var options = new ChargeCreateOptions
{
    Amount = 2000,
    Currency = "usd",
    Description = "Charge for jenny.rosen@example.com",
    SourceId = "tok_amex" // obtained with Stripe.js,
};
var service = new ChargeService();
Charge charge = service.Create(options);
```

Comment: It worked for me but I want to ask about card payments. How to give and validate card details?

Comment: @AsadNaeem Stripe will handle the approval and/or the decline of a credit card - what kind of card details did you want to get?

Comment: thanks for the reply. I am looking for the code to validate card details using .net code of stripe. I want to pass card number, its expiry and CVC number with amount etc.

Comment: I have validated the card using PaymentMethodCreateOptions. But after validating, how to make payment using the card details?

Comment: The _Create_ method of the _ChangeService_ makes the payment.

Comment: Stripe Payment Integration in Asp.net Web Forms and its 100 percent  working code and you can also download application 
https://code2night.com/Blog/MyBlog/Implement-Stripe-Payment-Gateway-In-ASPNET